# Скачивание закешированного файла

Tags: php

Некий PHP-скрипт генерирует .xls файл - счёт по заказу. Если его скачать, внести изменения в заказ и перегенерировать .xls, то файл соответственно изменяется с учётом изменений, однако браузер "скачивает" первоначальную версию файла, делая вид, что скачивает новую.

Проходит около часа без всяких изменений заказа и браузер скачивает уже нормальный новый .xls файл.

Отсюда мысли о неудалённом кеше.

Вопрос: Кеш ли это? Как можно генерировать файл .xls указав, что кеш надо потереть? Как можно скачивать файл, указав, что надо скачать именно новый, не закешированный файл? Варианты с изменением имени файла (с добавлением UNIX метки) не подходят по условию задачи.

Comment: Для управления кэшем смотрите в сторону заголовка [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Заголовки/Cache-Control)

Comment: чтобы получить веб-страницу не из кеша, добавляешь к ссылке рандомный и ничего не значащий GET параметр, например, www.site.ru/page1.html?var=rand. Будет ли это работать со скачиваемым файлом - я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно передать заголовок `Cache-Control: no-cache`

**Вариант 1**: Настроить заголовки посредством вашего веб серверка

К примеру для **nginx**:

```
location ~* \.(?:xls)$ {
    expires -1;
}
```

**Apache2**

```
<filesMatch "\.(xls)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Работает как в файле .httaccess так и в вашем конфиге

**Вариант 2:** Обрабатывать запрос к файлу средствами самого php, К примеру по запросу на адресс example.com/xls

И отдавать сам файл к примеру таким образом

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.xlsx\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
```